# parsing repeated lines of string based on initial characters

Tags: python, string, list

I am working on lists and strings in python. I have following lines of string.

```
ID abcd  
AC efg  
RF hij  
ID klmno  
AC p  
RF q
```

I want the output as :

```
abcd, efg, hij
klmno, p, q
```

This output is based on the the first two characters in the line. How can I achieve it in efficient way?

I'm looking to output the second part of the line for every entry between the `ID` tags.

Comment: I think we need some more details. In what way is it based on the first character in the line? Does the "ID" indicate the start of a new set of data? Are the first fields of the line always going to be in the same order as they are shown?

Comment: yes. ID indicate start of new data. whenever ID will come, data collection need to start till next ID encounters.

Comment: So what would the output be for something like

ID abcd
RF hij
AC efg

or is that input not possible?

Comment: no, first 3 characters will not come in output string, only characters after that till line ends will be taken. first 2 characters are only to identify the specific line

Comment: use `awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a little trouble parsing the question, but according to my best guess, this should do what you're looking for:

```
all_data = " ".join([line for line in file]).split("ID")
return [", ".join([item.split(" ")[::2] for item in all_data])]
```

Basically what you're doing here is first just joining together all of your data (removing the newlines) then splitting on your keyphrase of "ID"

After that, if I'm correctly interpreting the question, you're looking to get the second value of each pair. These pairs are space delimited (as is everything in that item due to the " ".join in the first line), so we just step through that list grabbing every other item.

In general splits have a little more syntactic sugar than is usually used, and the full syntax is: [start:end:step], so [::2] just returns every other item.

Comment: no its helpful because I am new in it and i dont understand why people downvote than helping. if i would had been master then i wouldnt even post a question. but u helped.

Comment: The reason for the downvotes is probably because this is a problem that has a wide variety of answers, and has already been encountered in many forms on Stack Overflow. If ever wonder why a question is being downvoted you should check this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @sam Also, don't forget to accept an answer if it was helpful to you.

Comment: says it has an invalid syntax

Comment: @sam There was a missing parenthesis. Added.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [default dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for line in lines:
    split_line = line.split(' ')
    result[split_line[0]].append(split_line[1])
```

This will give you a dictionary result that stores all the values that have the same key in an array. To get all the strings that were in a line that started with e.g. ID:

```
print result[ID]
```

Comment: OP actually posted a clarification that implies this might not be what they're looking for, though it would be useful for the example.

Comment: True. It seems more like your answer is the appropriate one to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following, which takes order into account so that transposing the dict's values makes more sense...

```
from collections import OrderedDict

items = OrderedDict()
with open('/home/jon/sample_data.txt') as fin:
    lines = (line.strip().partition(' ')[::2] for line in fin)
    for key, value in lines:
        items.setdefault(key[0], []).append(value)

res = [', '.join(el) for el in zip(*items.values())]
# ['abcd, efg, hij', 'klmno, p, q']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is best for this kind of parsing (do something until next token X)

```
import itertools

class GroupbyHelper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = None

    def __call__(self, row):
        if self.state is None:
            self.state = True
        else:
            if row[0] == 'ID':
                self.state = not self.state

        return self.state

# assuming you read data from 'stream'

for _, data in itertools.groupby((line.split() for line in stream), GroupbyHelper()):
    print ','.join(c[1] for c in data)
```

output:

```
$ python groupby.py
abcd,efg,hij
klmno,p,q
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answers in comments, this should work (if I understand what you're looking for):

```
data = None
for line in lines:
    fields = line.split(2)
    if fields[0] == "ID":
        #New set of data
        if data is not None:
            #Output last set of data.
            print ", ".join(data)
        data = []
    data.append(fields[1])

if data is not None:
    #Output final data set
    print ", ".join(data)
```

It's pretty straight forward, you're just collecting the second field in each line into `data` until you see that start of the next data set, at which point you output the previous data set.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you would like to sub group your data, when ever 'ID' is present as your key. Groupby solution could work wonder here, if you know how to group your data. Here is one such implementation that might work for you

```
>>> data=[e.split() for e in data.splitlines()]
>>> def new_key(key):
    toggle = [0,1]
    def helper(e):
        if e[0] == key:
            toggle[:] = toggle[::-1]
        return toggle[0]
    return helper

>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> for k,v in groupby(data, key = new_key('ID')):
    for e in v:
        print e[-1],
    print


abcd efg hij
klmno p q
```

Answer (score -1):

If lines is equal to

```
['ID abcd', 'AC efg', 'RF hij']
```

then

```
[line.split()[1] for line in lines]
```

**Edit**: Added everything below after down votes

I am not sure why this was down voted. I thought that code was the simplest way to get started with the information provided at the time. Perhaps this is a better explanation of what I thought/think the data was/is?

if input is a list of strings in repeated sequence, called alllines;

```
alllines = [ #a list of repeated lines of string based on initial characters
'ID abcd',
'AC efg', 
'RF hij', 
'ID klmno', 
'AC p', 
'RF q'
]
```

then code is;

```
[[line.split()[1] for line in lines] for lines in [[alllines.pop(0) \
for i in range(3)] for o in range(len(alllines)/3)]]
```

This basically says, create a sublist of three split [1] strings from the whole list of all strings for every three strings in the whole list.

and output is;

```
[[
'abcd', 'efg', 'hij'
], [
'klmno', 'p', 'q'
]]
```

**Edit: 8-6-13** This is an even better one without pop();

```
zip(*[iter([line.split()[1] for line in alllines])]*3)
```

with a slightly different output

```
[(
'abcd', 'efg', 'hij'
), (
'klmno', 'p', 'q'
)]
```